# How to apply search filter on table in IBM Carbon (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to IBM carbon design system
Below is table demo from IBM Carbon Angular documentation, 
The table.component.html

```
   <ibm-table-container>

<ibm-table-header>
    <h4 ibmTableHeaderTitle>DASHBOARD</h4>
</ibm-table-header>

<ibm-table-toolbar [model]="model" >
 <ibm-table-toolbar-content>
        <ibm-table-toolbar-search [expandable]="true" 
        placeholder=" Search in Dashboard ">
        </ibm-table-toolbar-search>
 </ibm-table-toolbar-content>
</ibm-table-toolbar>

<ibm-table [model]="model" > </ibm-table>
<ibm-pagination [model]="model" (selectPage)="selectPage($event)"></ibm-pagination>
```

The table.component.ts  file

```
    this.model.header = [
  new TableHeaderItem({data: "Name"}), new TableHeaderItem({data: "Address" })
];

this.model.data = [
       [new TableItem({data: "Data1"}), new TableItem({data: "India"})],
       [new TableItem({data: "Data2"}), new TableItem({data: "USA"})],
       [new TableItem({data: "Data3"}), new TableItem({data: "Canada"})],
       [new TableItem({data: "Data5"}), new TableItem({data: "France"})],

];
```

The documentation links that I am referring to:
[Storybook IBM Carbon table](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/components-table--with-toolbar-without-toolbar-action) , [Angular Carbon docs](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/documentation/components/Table.html) , [github angular carbon design](https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-angular/tree/master/src/table)

[This is the screenshot of the table UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glJs5.png)

can someone please show me a live example for search filter on table possibly on stackblitz ?

[Stackblitz editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ouddc5?embed=1&file=src/app/&view=editor)

Comment: If you desire someone show you something on stackblitz you might create a stackblitz boilerplate please.

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz editor link in my question

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna search ? If you search "India" it check the India checkbox ?

Comment: If I search India than only the rows with India in it should be display and all the rows without india should be filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly get search value changes:

```
<ibm-table-toolbar-search [expandable]="true" placeholder="Search in Dashboard" (change)="searchValueChange($event.value)"></ibm-table-toolbar-search>
```

Then filter data with the value:

```
searchValueChange(value: string) {
  this.model.data = this.model.data.filter(
    (item) => item[0].data.includes(e.value) || item[1].data.includes(e.value)
  )
}
```

Problem now is when you'll change the value of the searchbar it will try to filter from the previous filtered values. For fixing this you may store initial data into a initialData property and filtering initialData instead filteredData. (If you need help for that tell me in comments).

Comment: Thank you ! and  I need help with the rest of the part.

Comment: Create another post so :)

Comment: I have created another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609649/how-to-get-initial-table-data-after-filterdata-is-applied-on-table-in-ibm-carbon     :)