# How to get initial table data after filterdata is applied on table in IBM-carbon (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The search bar:

```
<ibm-table-toolbar-search [expandable]="true" placeholder="Search in Dashboard" (change)="searchValueChange($event.value)"></ibm-table-toolbar-search>
```

The search value change function:

```
  searchValueChange(value: string) {
  this.model.data = this.model.data.filter(
    (item) => item[0].data.includes(e.value) || item[1].data.includes(e.value)
  )
}
```

After applying the search filter I am unable to get intial data on clearing the search bar.

Comment: Create a copy of the data and put it back when `e.value` contains nothing. Like `this.orig_data = [...this.model.data]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  TableModel,
  TableItem,
  TableHeaderItem
} from "carbon-components-angular";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  copyData = [];
  @Input() model = new TableModel();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model.header = [
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Name" }),
      new TableHeaderItem({ data: "Address" })
    ];

    this.model.data = [
      [new TableItem({ data: "Data1" }), new TableItem({ data: "India" })],
      [new TableItem({ data: "Data2" }), new TableItem({ data: "USA" })],
      [new TableItem({ data: "Data3" }), new TableItem({ data: "Canada" })],
      [new TableItem({ data: "Data4" }), new TableItem({ data: "China" })],
      [new TableItem({ data: "Data5" }), new TableItem({ data: "Italy" })]
    ];

    this.copyData = [...this.model.data];
  }

  searchValueChange(value: string) {
    if (value) {
      this.model.data = this.model.data.filter(
        item =>
          item[0].data.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) ||
          item[1].data.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
      );
    } else {
      this.model.data = this.copyData;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
copyData = this.model.data;  
searchValueChange(value: string) {
if(value){
   this.model.data = this.model.data.filter(
        (item) => item[0].data.includes(e.value) || item[1].data.includes(e.value)
      )
}else{
   this.model.data = this.copyData
}

}
```

Comment: It is not working I have done this in stackblitz   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ouddc5?embed=1&file=src/app/&view=editor